# FFMPEG Split video into random durations within range

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg

I want to split a video into parts, but not equal parts.

I want each clip to be between 15 and 50 seconds. But I want each clip length to be random (within that 15 to 50 second range).

How would I do this with ffmpeg in the command line?

This is the command I was using for splitting a video into equal parts

```
ffmpeg -i lutherceleb.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy   -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4
```

Comment: For which shell? Bash, Windows command prompt, PowerShell, or what? The solution might depend on the shell you're using.

Comment: mac terminal is the command line i am using

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky, but you can use any scripting language (e.g., Ruby) to generate a random list of split times. Just change the total duration (150 here) and then assign the output of that script to the option `-segment_times`

```
$ times=$(ruby -e 's=[]; d=0; while d < 150 do t=rand(15..50); s << (d+t); d=d+t end; puts s.join(",")')
$ echo $times
15,53,96,124,168
$ ffmpeg -i lutherceleb.mp4 -f segment -segment_times $times -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4
```

You can shorten `-acodec copy -vcodec copy` to `-c copy`.